# Create a CSV file of a 2D matrix of zeros using bash, or tiniest bit of python where not possible in bash

Tags: python, bash, data-science

This is for a numerical data science application. I need to create a matrix of zeros, in a file, separated by commas (within a line) and ending with newline (at end of each line). This bash code was the closest:

```
l=`python -c "print(f'{\"0, \" * 9}0')"`  # 10 zeros comma separated in one line
yes $l | head -n 3  # print line 3 times
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

That’s fine as far as it goes, until you try to change the two literals 9 and 3 to shell variables. However, it is difficult (to me) to code it correctly to replace literal 9 with a shell variable n=9. I tried using bash and python but still not working. 
For example these two different attempts don’t actually work (for me) with variables:

```
l=$(printf '0,%.0s' {1..$((n-1))}; printf '0')  # 100% bash code
yes $l | head -n $k  # print line 3 times
0,0
0,0
0,0

l=`python -c "print(f'{\"0, \" * 9}0')"`  # using a bit of python, 10 literal zeros comma separated in one line
yes $l | head -n 3  # print line 3 times
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

In this case, changing literal 9 to variable in the python was even worse, and gave me something crazy, like some kind of directory listing, which I definitely don’t want.

Comment: Are the blanks after the commas required, or would `0,0,0` also work?

Comment: Blanks are optional. Your way is OK.

Comment: `print(','.join(itertools.repeat('0', 10)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a slight variation on your approach:

```sh
n=10
k=3
yes "$(yes 0 | head -n "$n" | paste -s -d,)" | head -n "$k"
```

And if blanks after the commas are required, piping to `sed 's/,/, /g'` would do that.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson Bash calling external but common utilities, to be precise ;) Shawn's answer is pure Bash.

Answer (score 2):

In pure bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cols=$1
rows=$2
declare -a row
for ((i = 0; i < cols; i++)); do
    row+=(0)
done
IFS=, line="${row[*]}"
for ((i = 0; i < rows; i++)); do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Example:

```
$ ./demo.sh 10 3
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question but as often happens, I figured out a good working answer soon after posting!  I just combined a couple of other SO answers together. Thank you in advance for other people that find anything simpler than mine, as always.

This works right:

```
export n
yes `python -c "import os; n=int(os.environ['n']); print(f'{\"0.0, \" * n}0.0')"` | head -n $k
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

This still might help other numerical programmers in my opinion.